# Can't get Pango-sharp gravity attibute to work

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

I am unable to get the gravity attribute to work with a pango layout. I've tried both using markup and I'm not getting any errors or warnings from the markup parser:

```
l.SetMarkup ("<span gravity=\"east\" color=\"black\">" + text + "</span>");
```

and with inserting and changing the attribute into the layout AttrList:

```
l.Attributes.Insert (new Pango.AttrGravity (Pango.Gravity.East));
```

but neither draws the text vertically. AttrList.Change occasionally crashes the program as well. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong or if gravity works at all with Gtk#?

Here is the snippet of the all the code:

```
Pango.Layout l = new Pango.Layout (PangoContext);
l.FontDescription = Pango.FontDescription.FromString ("Courier New 11");
l.SetMarkup ("<span gravity=\"east\" color=\"black\">" + text + "</span>");
GdkWindow.DrawLayout (Style.TextGC (StateType.Normal), x, y, l);
l.Dispose ();
```

Thanks

EDIT:

I found a Gravity property under `FontDescription` but it only causes errors along the lines of 'that font can't be found....'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption is that gravity is bound to the text you're trying to display. So if it's Chinese, gravity east should work (or is perhaps enabled by default in this case).

If you want to rotate a layout, you can induce rotation with a matrix:

```
Pango.Layout l = new Pango.Layout (PangoContext);

// Matrix.Identity is a 'no transformation' matrix.
var matrix = Pango.Matrix.Identity;

// A rotation of 90 degrees.
matrix.Rotate(90); 

// Assign the matrix to the Pango context.
l.Context.Matrix = matrix;

l.SetMarkup(@"<span color=""black"">Hello, world!</span>");

GdkWindow.DrawLayout(Style.TextGC(StateType.Normal), 50, 50, l);
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I wanted. I saw some stuff about matrix in Python's Gtk implementation but sometimes its kind of hard to decipher between that and C#'s Gtk wrapper.